Soundness check: Set commitment using KZG and polynomial of form (x - e_1)(x - e_2)...(x - e_n)
We wish to create a commitment scheme to a set of at most $n$ unique elements, $\{ e_1, e_2, ... e_n\}$. Is a KZG commitment of max degree $n$ to the following degree $n$ polynomial, where each element is a root of the polynomial, a sound construction?
$$
p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - e_i) \\
= (x - e_1)(x - e_2)...(x - e_n)
$$
In a regular KZG scheme, the prover proves the correct evaluation of $p(a)$ for any given $a$.
In this scheme, the prover proves an element $a$ is part of the committed set by proving $p(a) = 0$.
Can an attacker forge a proof for $p(a) = 0$ where $a$ is not part of the committed set?
Bonus:
If this is a sound construction, how can we efficiently update the commitment for the following operations?

removal of an element from the set
addition of an element into the set

